# Regex finding the pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How to find the below pattern is there or not in a given string using Regex or any other methods in C#

```
NAME <some text here> RANK
```

The spaces coming after NAME,before RANK and after RANK should be considered. The text between <> will vary.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the question (specifically the first line). What is is you're after? Also, **what have you already tried**?

Comment: Do you need to get also NAME and RANK? or do you want to leave those words outside the results?

Comment: @BradChristie, I think the first line means that he's looking for `Regex.IsMatch` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var result = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"NAME\s.*?\sRANK\s{3}");
```

Comment: +1 just for being the only one to recognize an ungreedy match.

Comment: Even though '.*?' is ungreedy, it could match past the first RANK because of the trailing requirement '\s{3}' 'NAME <some text here> RANK and NAME finally RANK ' in ' NAME <some text here> RANK and NAME finally RANK<sp><sp><sp>'. Also if `NAME\s\sRANK` where \s\s is a forced requirement. I think the user questions is ambiguous though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/, it's a pretty useful resource for learning Regex.  In C#, take a look at the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace, specifically the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class.

Answer (score 1):

From the requirements, these might work (I'm still not sure about some of the boundry conditions in your description).

`NAME(?=[ ]).+?(?<=[ ])RANK(?=[ ])`

or

`(?<=^|[ ])NAME(?=[ ]).+?(?<=[ ])RANK(?=[ ]|$)`

The dot doesen't include newlines. It can be replaced with [\s\S] or you can simply add (?s) at the begining to include them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use :

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(input, "NAME .* RANK")) 
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply do

```
string s = "NAME sdhfg hgfjh sjfg gf RANK".Replace("NAME ","").Replace(" RANK","");
```